# Webservice to SQL server phonegap app

Tags: sql, cordova, webmethod

I'm creating a Phonegap application that needs to connect to an SQL database and return the data to the application.

How can i set up a WebMethod that will:

1. Create a connection to the database
2. Query the database for any records
3. Return found records to the mobile app

I'm using Phonegap Build so i cannot really use any plugins and the Webservice and SQL database are hosted on my computer, so I will be connecting to them through 192.168.xxx.xxx.

EDIT:
So far i have a this calling to the web service from the Javascript:

index.js::

```
var url = "http://192.168.xxx.xxx:1234/"
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: url + "WebService.asmx/HelloWorld",
        data: "{}",
        success: function (data) {
        $("#ul_DeviceList").append('<li>Example ' + data.d + '</li>').listview('refresh');
        },
        error: function (data) {
        alert(data.status + " : " + data.statusText);
        }
});
```

WebService.cs::

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
```

This is so i can tell if the device has connected to the Server, which it does.

Now i believe need to do something along the lines of :

```
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        [WebMethod]
        public void GetData()
        {
            SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(*Connection string will go here*);
            conn.Open();
           ..etc etc...
```

But at the moment i cannot seem to add System.data.SqlServerCe to my project..

Comment: show us what you've done so far (some code), and where you stuck at

Answer (score 0):

well, I can not help you with C# or whatever language this is. This is beyond my knowledge.

As far as I know you can query your web service if you open it localy right from your browser. If you can not, then you could use a free product called **[SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/)** witch is designed to query web services

First of all try to deal with serverside: connect to your database, write test method to return sample data from database and only then go to javascript.

By the way, your HelloWorld method returns not JSON structure, as your ajax method expects to get data in JSON format.

You are on right path, just need to go futher :) If you need some help- just ask. Good luck